# JSF ajax and jQueryMobile update selectmenus

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-mobile, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0, jQuery 1.8.2 and jQueryMobile 1.2.0

I have two selectmenus, where source values of the second menu depends on selection of first selectmenu (values are loaded by backing bean function). My problem is I can't correctly update the second selectmenu when I choose option in first selectmenu.

```
<h:form id="testForm" prependId="false">
 <h:selectOneMenu id="testValues" value="#{model.testValue}" >
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{bean.getTestValues()}"
                var="object"
                itemLabel="#{object.label}"
                itemValue="#{object.value}" />
            <f:ajax render="testValues2" onevent="initForm"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:selectOneMenu id="testValues2" value="#{model.testValue2}">
          <f:selectItems
                value="#{bean.getTest2Values(model.testValue)}"
                var="object2"
                itemLabel="#{object2.label}"
                itemValue="#{object2.value}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initForm(){
    $("#testForm").trigger('create');

    };
     </script>
```

When I do that, testValues2 menu is not created correcty. Something: like that:

```
<div class="ui-select"> <!-- menuselect before update... -->
     <div>...</div> <!-- here is selected option from testValues2 before update -->
    <div class="ui-select">...</div> <!-- menu with updated values-->
</div>
```

It's obvious  that I want to display correctly only menu after updating.
I tried to refresh second selectmenu by:

```
$('#testValues2').selectmenu('refresh');
```

or

```
$('#testValues2').selectmenu();
$('#testValues2').selectmenu('refresh');
```

but it didn't help (I had error: `Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`)

Also I can't render all form by `<f:ajax render=":testForm"` /> because I have on the form other fields which I don't want to refresh.

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to [this problem](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=28380) I found in PrimeFaces Mobile

Comment: Your `onevent` handler is at least strange. Are you aware that `<f:ajax onevent>` is merely a listener method which is invoked 3 times during an ajax request? I'm not exactly sure what `$("#testForm").trigger('create');` does, but are you absolutely sure that it needs to be invoked all those times?